As a Reddit subreddit moderator, how do I prefill Reddit title and text boxes without CSS?
As a Reddit subreddit moderator, I am too tech-illiterate to utilize CSS. Can this be resolved more easily without CSS?

When you click submit link [in this subreddit], there is text already in the title box, and a message already in the text box that disappears as you add text.

Source: This Reddit /r/csshelp post in February 2014.
For example, /r/FullLengthFilms and /r/MiniSwap  prefill the title box.
r/24HourSupport prefills the text box.

